# My phpmailer script goes to spam

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, spam

I know this question has already been asked but no answers help me though.

Here is my code i hope you can find something wrong.

```
   <?php
    require("phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
    require("phpMailer/class.smtp.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();   
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication         
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;  
    $mail->Username = "mailer@example.com";  // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = "validpassword"; // SMTP password

    $mail->From = "mailer@example.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Mailer";
    $mail->AddAddress("my.email@gmail.com");
    $mail->AddReplyTo("mailer@example.com", "Mailer");

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters

    $mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
    $mail->Body    = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
    $mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";

    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
       echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
       echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       exit;
    }

    echo "Message has been sent";
    ?>
```

PS : Funny fact is that my mail doesn't go in spam with the mailer()... But i have to use Phpmailer.

Comment: What differences do you see in the header when you use `mail()` versus `PHPMailer`?

Comment: if it lands in spam folder, there could be a chance that there is an additional header in your email explaining the spamscore and treshold. (spamfighter and spamassassin do this afaik)

Comment: Is it exactly the same email to the same address that goes to spam ?

Comment: @Bamar `$headers .='Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"'."\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit"'."\n";
 $headers .= "Date:" . $entetedate . "\n";`


@Anigel I don't understand your question sorry, maybe my english is not as good as i thougth.

Comment: You say it goes to spam with phpmailer but not if you use mail. Are you sending the same email to the same email address with both methods?

Comment: I don't mean the headers in the PHP script, I mean the headers when you view the received message. Are there differences in headers like `Received:`?

Comment: BTW, if you want me to see your comments, spell my name right. SO provides TAB completion of usernames, so there's no excuse for typos. Just type '@b<tab>`.

Answer (score 0):

To see if the mail server that you are sending these through has a glaring problem that would cause other mail servers to think it's a spammer, try sending a message from your script to check-auth@verifier.port25.com. This service will do a bunch of checks, and you'll get a report back with ton of information, such weather or not your mail server's DNS is setup correctly, whether your mail server's IP is on any black lists, if you have a problem with your SPF records, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Your mail is going to spam, ergo your mail is being sent, ergo there is (probably) nothing wrong with your script. There are many reasons why mail is delivered to spam. Most obviously, it might **be** spam. You should be checking the configuration of your mail configuration, specifically check for correct SPF and DKIM records. If you're using a third-party mailing service check that they haven't themselves been blacklisted. Check your return addresses make sense and are valid. Trace the path from the headers and see where any warnings are added en route. And finally, check your own spam filters.

Comment: Why would any of that depend on which mail API he uses?

Comment: Ok I check those SPF and DKIM records and i'll tell you if i have new.

Comment: @Barmar The code posted uses PHPMailer and specifically uses SMTP. If it's logging in to a 3rd party service then mail will follow a different route from that used by the PHP mail() function that will use `sendmail` on the host server. A different path can invalidate SPF records, or send mail through a blacklited server.

Answer (score -1):

```
   //servidor smtp
   $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
   //Muy importante para que llegue a hotmail y otros 
   $mail->Helo = "localhost";
   //Asignamos a Host el nombre de nuestro servidor smtp
   $mail->Host = "localhost";
   $mail->Port = 25;
```